# PHP form won't submit

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've been trying to figure out why my form won't submit. Nothing happens when I click the submit button. After a whole evening of trying, rewriting, searching,.. I just don't see what's wrong with my code. Anyone who can help me? Would be highly appreciated..

```
    <form method="POST" id="newdiscussion form" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Select a category</span>
      <select class="form-control" name="category">
        <option value="Experiences">Flying experiences</option>
        <option value="Training">Training</option>
        <option value="Trips">Trips</option>
        <option value="Places/Airports">Places &amp Airports</option>
        <option value="Buying">Buying an aircraft</option>
        <option value="Technical/Building">Technical &amp Building</option>
        <option value="Events">Events</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Topic</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required maxlength="30" name="topic">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Location <small> (optional)</small></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="location">
    </div>

  <textarea id="txtEditor" name="txtEditor"></textarea>

    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" >Thumbnail</span>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="thumbnail" required>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="post" name="post" >Post story</button>

  </form>

<?php

function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
     };


    $file_name=$_FILES["thumbnail"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["thumbnail"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["thumbnail"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "thumbnails/".$imagename;

if(isset($_POST['post']) && move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path) ){

    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$log_username);
    $topic=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['topic']);
    $story=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['txtEditor']);
    $category=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['category']);
    $location=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['location']);

$result=mysqli_query($db_conx,"INSERT INTO stories (`username`,`topic`,`story`,`category`,`location`,`thumbnail`) VALUES('$username','$topic','$story','$category','$location','$imagename')");

   $resultgoto = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT id from stories WHERE story = '$story' AND topic = '$topic' AND username = '$username'");
   $gotorecord = mysqli_fetch_array($resultgoto);
   header("Location: http://hangarflights.net46.net/stories/story.php?id=".$gotorecord['id']);

}

?>
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: I've tried it all and I also looked at the possible duplicate question with answers, but I just can't get it to work..

Comment: Yes I already edited that. But it doesn't fix my problem :(

Comment: I've reopened your question. Now, if you're not getting any errors, then something more bizarre is happening. You sure you're using error checking on PHP and MySQL here?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Fred-ii- , it's really appreciated. You said something about error reporting, so I just added the line `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the bottom of my php code and it mysteriously works now.. So thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome Senne, glad to have been of help, *cheers*.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's posting to the php file you think it is?

Try changing your form tag to

```
<form method="POST" action="submitFile.php" id="newdiscussionform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I also took out the space from the id.

Comment: It was submitting to the same file of course (empty action).